# De Rham=type decomposition with 3 or more complementary integrable distributions

Tags: differential-geometry

For a smooth manifold $M$ with two complementary integrable distributions $D_1$ and $D_2$ (so $TM = D_1 \oplus D_2$) one can find a compatible coordinate system about any point, also known as a 'flat' coordinate system.

So the first dimension $D_1$ coordinates are the coordinate vectors for integral manifolds of $D_1$ and the last ones are for those of $D_2$. This is the statement of the Lemma below Proposition 5.2 in Kobayashi-Nomizu Volume 1, chapter 4, page 182). The proof is the idea from De Rham's original paper.

Does the idea used in this proof, (taking the first $\dim D_2$ coordinates for a coordinate system adapted to $D_2$, and the last $\dim D_1$ coordinates for a coordinate system adapted to $D_1$) extend to the case where there are three or more integrable distributions $TM = D_1 \oplus D_2 \oplus D_3 \oplus \dots + D_k$ (where $k \geq 3$)?

There would need to be some modified way to shift around the coordinates since in this case choosing the first few coordinates as for $D_1 \oplus D_2$ above seemingly leaves no "room" to pick coordinates for integral manifolds of the remaining distributions.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use the idea of the proof to add local coordinate systems appropriately for each of the distributions.

Comment: Isn't thjere a problem with the overlap? Say we have 3 complementary distributions, D1+D2+D3 = TM (direct sum), dimensions k1, k2,k3.
Let (x1,...,xn)= coords adapted to D1, so integral mfds for D1 are given by fixing the last k2+k3 coords.

Let (y1,...,yn)= coords adapted to D2, so integral mfds for D2 are given by fixing the first k1 and the last k3 coords.

Let (z1,...,zn)= coords adapted to D3, so integral mfds for D3 are given by fixing the first k1+k2.

The DeRham idea is that you use the fixed coordinates to form the coords that accommodate all the int mfds for D1, D2 and D3.

Comment: For D1 we need to fix x(k1+1),...,x(n) to get integral mfds, 

For D2 we need to fix y(1),...,y(k1) and y(k3+1),...y(n) . to get integral mfds, 

For D3 we need to fix z(1),...,z(k1+k2) to get integral mfds for D3.

How do you put all these x's, y's and z's in one coord system (w1,w2,..,wn)?

Comment: When there are just two distrbutions, D1+D2, you can use the coordinates (y1,...,yk1,x(k1+1),,,,x(k1+k2)=xn). But with 3 or more distributions the choices of x's, y';s and z's overlap so there is not a clear choice of which to choose where. Or am I being dense?

Comment: No, they won't overlap because of independence of the distributions. :) Just keep choosing transverse coordinates.

Comment: The integral mfds will not overlap but I meant the choices of which of the x's y's or z's to use in the one final coordinate system. For example, which of the choices of x or y do you use in the last k3 coordinates? You need the last k3 coords to be constant in x to get D1-integral mfds, and you need the last k3 coords to be constant in y to get D2-integral mfds. So what are the last k3 coords in the final coord system that accommodates int mfds of D1, D2 and D3?

Comment: We should get coordinate systems $\{x^1,\dots,x^{n_1},y^{n_1+1},\dots,y^n\}$, $\{x^{n_1+1},\dots,x^{n_1+n_2},z^{\dots}\}$, $\{x^{n_1+n_2+1},\dots,x^{n_1+n_2+n_3}, w^{\dots}\}$, $\dots$, $\{x^{n_1+n_2+\dots+n_{k-1}+1},\dots,x^{n_1+n_2+\dots+n_{k-1}+n_k},q^{\dots}\}$ so that $\partial/\partial{x^i}$ span $D_1$ for $i=1,\dots,n_1$, span $D_2$ for $i=n_1+1,\dots,n_1+n_2$, $\dots$, span $D_k$ for $i=n_1+\dots+n_{k-1}+1,\dots,n_1+\dots+n_k$.

Comment: That is a correct method for finding one coordinate system with the coordinate vectors spanning the distributions. But it is the 'opposite' strategy from the one I was asking about. 
Sat there are just two complementary distrbutions :

D1 with local coords (x1,...,xn), and varying x1,...x(k1) gives the integral mfds for D1

D2 with local coords (y1,...,yn), and varying y(k1+1),...y(k1+k2=n) gives the integral mfds for D2.

Then I believe the method you posted amounts to using the coord system
( x1,...x(k1), y(k1+1),...y(k1+k2=n))

DeRham's proof is to use the coord

Comment: X = (y1,...y(k1),x(k1+1),...x(n=k1+k2))
So fixing the first k1 coords of X gives int mfds for D2 and fixing the last k2 coords of X gives D1 int mfds.

The question is whether this second DeRham coord system, using the coords you fix to get the int mfds, can be extended to three or more distributions?

Comment: I see your point. The normal bundles of the distributions are not going to be disjoint at all, so there's no way that I can see to do it "the other way."

Comment: Thanks very much for your extensive feedback!